# Does AWS have an image processing service?

Tags: google-app-engine, image-processing, amazon-web-services, imagemagick

At past I have used ImageMagick in order to code some web app that performs some image processing. 
Then I encountered this from Google App engine -

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/

Which looks quite interesting, however I would like to work with AWS related technologies, and I wonder if AWS have a similar service?

Thanks,
Yair

Answer (score 1):

No they don't have an image processing service. They do have transcoding services for audio and video, though:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html

But that's not what you are looking for. The closest you can get to that with AWS is probably by creating your own on-demand instance which can process a batch of images and then stops again. Or maybe have a look into Data Pipelines or Simple Workflows. Might be overkill for what you want to achieve, though, depending on the scale.